# How do count forward X number of days into future in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I need to be able to count forward X number of dates into the future in PHP. For example, 14 days from today is what date? What routines in PHP can be used for this? Thanks!

Comment: this isn't a bad question. why all the downvotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy with [`date()`](http://php.net/date) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+14 days'));
```

You can also use [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+14 days');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Or:

```
$date = new DateTime('+14 days');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
echo (new DateTime('+14 days'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Or with [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P14D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: `echo (new DateTime('+14 days'))->format('Y-m-d');` not the type of "one-liner" I'd give a brunette, that's for sure (grin). +1 though on the "coding side" of it. ;-)